# IE 11 displaying some strange characters in Dojo content pane

Tags: dojo, internet-explorer-11, dojo-1.9

I am using Dojo Accordian Container, the content panes inside the accordian are just displaying text. Everything works fine in firefox, chrome except for IE 11. Below are snapshots of the issue

[image: Issue]

When I do something on the browser, like say If I open developer tools, the correct text gets displayed

[image: Works]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using this in your HTML??

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
```

I've had many problems with IE and dojo in the past.  Firefox and Chrome always seem to work perfectly.  It's just a stab in the dark but the line above fixed many similar problems for me.

Comment: Tried, doesn't seem to help me.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of to try is to hold your mouse pointer over the problem element, right-click and select Inspect Element to possibly help debug why this problem is occurring in the web browser.

Comment: yes I have already checked the element, but the problem is when I do that inspection using the developer tools, the correct text appears.